# How to re-sample and interpolate new data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation, resampling

I have a csv file containing the following information:

```
Time(s) Variable
0.003   1
0.009   2
0.056   3
0.094   4
0.4     5
0.98    6
1.08    7
1.45    8
1.89    9
2.45    10
2.73    11
3.2     12
3.29    13
3.5     14
```

I would like to be able to be able to change the time column into 0.25s intervals starting from 0, and have the associated variable data change along with it (i.e if at 2.45 v=10, at 2.5 v=10.2). The variable data would have to be interpolated against the change in the time data I assume? I need to be able to do this straight from csv rather than writing out the data in python as the real data-set is 1000's of rows.

Not sure if what I want is exactly possible but some thoughts would go along way, thanks!

Comment: You have to look into interpolation a little and decide what kind you want. Linear and spline are popular choices.

Answer (score 1):

How about Scipy's interp1d

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

interp = interp1d(df['Time(s)'], df['Variable'])

new_times = np.arange(0.25, 3.5, 0.25)
pd.DataFrame({'Time(s)': new_times, 'Variable':interp(new_times)})
```

Output:

```
    Time(s)   Variable
0      0.25   4.509804
1      0.50   5.172414
2      0.75   5.603448
3      1.00   6.200000
4      1.25   7.459459
5      1.50   8.113636
6      1.75   8.681818
7      2.00   9.196429
8      2.25   9.642857
9      2.50  10.178571
10     2.75  11.042553
11     3.00  11.574468
12     3.25  12.555556
```

Comment: Hi Quang, this seems like it's going to do the job, however when using my real data I get this message 'A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.'. I have changed the np.arrange values to correspond with the new data.

Comment: Nvm Quang, I've sorted it. This method is perfect for what I needed, thanks!